# How find specific data value from html tag in BeautifulSoup4?

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I have a following html and I need to extract TOWN GMBH.

```
<span class="font-semibold" data-qa="companyName">TOWN GMBH</span>
```

I could do following:

```
bs = BeautifulSoup('<span class="font-semibold" data-qa="companyName">TOWN GMBH</span>', "html5lib")

bs.find(class_='font-semibold').contents
```

But font-semibold is not unique, and there are several of them on the page. How can I specifically address html where data-qa="companyName" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either a dictionary of attributes to be used for filtering:

```
bs.find(attrs={'class': 'font-semibold', 'data-qa': 'companyName'})
```

Or, use a more concise [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
bs.select_one('.font-semibold[data-qa=companyName]')
```

And, to get the text, I'd use [`.get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) method instead of using `.contents`.